# How do I use a DefaultPartitioner with sendDefault method of Spring-kafka kafkaTemplate

Tags: spring-kafka

I am trying to send a message to a topic with 4 partitions.And I want the message to go the partition as decided by the DefaultPartitioner(which uses the hash of the key)

`kafkaTemplate.sendDefault(DefaultPartitioner(job.getId()),job.getId(),job);`

I am not sure how to make the kafkaTemplate use the DefaultPartitioner to get the partition number.

Could someone please help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from JavaDocs!

```
/**
 * The default partitioning strategy:
 * <ul>
 * <li>If a partition is specified in the record, use it
 * <li>If no partition is specified but a key is present choose a partition based on a hash of the key
 * <li>If no partition or key is present choose a partition in a round-robin fashion
 */
public class DefaultPartitioner implements Partitioner {
```

---

```
/**
 * Send the data to the default topic with the provided key and no partition.
 * @param key the key.
 * @param data The data.
 * @return a Future for the {@link SendResult}.
 */
ListenableFuture<SendResult<K, V>> sendDefault(K key, V data);
```

So, if you would like to rely on the `DefaultPartitioner`, all you need is a `key` for the record. Therefore just use that particular `KafkaTemplate` method:

```
kafkaTemplate.sendDefault(job.getId(),job);
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked.I was having issues with the kafka tool I was using to check the partitions.I used the kafka console consumer instead and I could see the messages in the expected partition.